# ROS C++ Dynamic Reconfigure bind error

Tags: boost, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I've got problem with Dynamic reconfigure. I want to create bind function for DynamicGUI Class due to tutorial, but something is wrong.
All Dynamic reconfigure functionality is in DynamicGUI Class.

DynamicGui.h

```
#include <gateway_sim/SimulationConfig.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#ifndef DYNAMICGUI_H
#define DYNAMICGUI_H

class DynamicGUI
{
public:
    DynamicGUI();
    ~DynamicGUI();

    ethercat_gateway::DOutput GatewayOutput; 
    ethercat_gateway::DAInput GatewayInput;

    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<gateway_sim::SimulationConfig> dParamServer;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<gateway_sim::SimulationConfig>::CallbackType f;
    void paramCb(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig &config, uint32_t level);
};

#endif
```

DynamicGui.cpp

```
#include <gateway_sim/DynamicGui.h>

DynamicGUI::DynamicGUI()
{
    f= boost::bind(&DynamicGUI::paramCb, _1, _2);
    dParamServer.setCallback(f);
}

void DynamicGUI::paramCb(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig &config, uint32_t level)
{
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch1 = config.Output_value_Ch1;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch2 = config.Output_value_Ch2;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch3 = config.Output_value_Ch3;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch4 = config.Output_value_Ch4;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch5 = config.Output_value_Ch5;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch6 = config.Output_value_Ch6;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch7 = config.Output_value_Ch7;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch8 = config.Output_value_Ch8;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch9 = config.Output_value_Ch9;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch10 = config.Output_value_Ch10;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch11 = config.Output_value_Ch11;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch12 = config.Output_value_Ch12;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch13 = config.Output_value_Ch13;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch14 = config.Output_value_Ch14;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch15 = config.Output_value_Ch15;
    GatewayOutput.Output_value_Ch16 = config.Output_value_Ch16;
}
```

The Class is created in ControlNode node.

```
#include <gateway_sim/ControlNode.h>
#include<gateway_sim/DynamicGui.h>
#include <signal.h>

ControlNode::ControlNode() : TurckIO (nh), Motor1(nh,"s1"), Motor2 (nh, "s2") 
{

  DynamicGUI Reconfigurate();
    ControlDataTimer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.01), &ControlNode::timerCallback, this);
    ControlDataTimer1s = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(1), &ControlNode::timerCallback1s, this);

}
```

I receive error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/include/gateway_sim/ControlNode.h:11,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/include/gateway_sim/DynamicGui.h:2,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/src/DynamicGui.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int)>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1284:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >’
/home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/src/DynamicGui.cpp:7:50:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:37: error: ‘void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
   75 |     typedef typename F::result_type type;
      |                                     ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:58,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:71,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/include/gateway_sim/ControlNode.h:11,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/include/gateway_sim/DynamicGui.h:2,
                 from /home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/src/DynamicGui.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker2<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&; T1 = unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:931:38:   required from ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&; T1 = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:720:7:   required from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&; T1 = unsigned int; typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1068:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&; T1 = unsigned int; typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1121:5:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), boost::function<R(T0, T1)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >; R = void; T0 = gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&; T1 = unsigned int; typename boost::enable_if_<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), boost::function<R(T0, T1)>&>::type = boost::function<void(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int)>&]’
/home/kamil/catkin_ws/src/gateway_sim/src/DynamicGui.cpp:7:50:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:158:11: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (DynamicGUI::*)(gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DynamicGUI*>, boost::arg<1> > >) (gateway_sim::SimulationConfig&, unsigned int)’
  158 |           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN((*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [gateway_sim/CMakeFiles/simulation_node.dir/build.make:128: gateway_sim/CMakeFiles/simulation_node.dir/src/DynamicGui.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1693: gateway_sim/CMakeFiles/simulation_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

I have no idea what should be done to make it correct.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398049/ros-c++-dynamic-reconfigure-bind-error/) by [kamiln497](https://answers.ros.org/users/100561/kamiln497/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved.

in .h file:

```
dynamic_reconfigure::Server<gateway_sim::SimulationConfig> dParamServer;
dynamic_reconfigure::Server<gateway_sim::SimulationConfig>::CallbackType f;
```

In .cpp:

```
f= boost::bind(&DynamicGUI::paramCb, this, _1, _2);
dParamServer.setCallback(f);
```

---

Originally posted by [kamiln497](https://answers.ros.org/users/100561/kamiln497/) with karma: 16 on 2022-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0